# jQuery confliction for Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have loaded two jQuery versions on my page;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var jq = jQuery.noConflict();</script>

<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to use the Autocomplete plugin from https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/ (it doesn't work with 1.4.2) so I have to add 1.9.1 jQuery version.

I cannot remove 1.4.2 at all, as removing so breaks my existing code.

I have tried changing the order of the libraries but no luck.

FYI `jq("#elem").hide();` etc. works and other jQuery native stuff. but when I use it to bind autocomplete plugin, it fails driving me crazy;

binding as  `jq('#searchbox').autocomplete();` the error I see in console is

> TypeError: jq(...).autocomplete is not a function

PS: I have also tried `<script>var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>` without success.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The error is just on the autocomplete? Can you select elements for example with both versions?

Comment: @CarlosMartins Yes, I mentioned in the question, that other stuff works like jq("#elem").hide(); etc. for both versions. it's just the plugin, it's not recognizing.

Comment: Are you using the  jQuery UI library? There is a Known Issue related with this https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: No, I am not using jQuery UI and I have already tried their provided alternate function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work you. I got no error on this.

```js
jq('#autocomplete').autocomplete({});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.27/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = $.noConflict(true);

</script>

<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete"/> no error
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm, by moving plugin js file before including other jquery did the job.